# Azure AD: Office 365 Groups - how to create an email alias to an "Office" group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Does anyone know how to create an email alias for an "Office" group on Office 365 Azure AD?  The current email address that comes with the group is random numbers and letters.
[Office365 Office Group ScreenSnip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPKmK.png)

I know you can create them for Distribution groups, but not sure how to do this for an "Office" group.

Thanks in advance!

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're trying to create this group via code or UI, so I'll try to give you both.

In code: According to [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_groups) you should be able to specify the email alias when you create the group by setting the `mailNickname` attribute.

In UI: When you name the group, there's a field direclty below the name that displays the email address that will be created for the group.  By default the email is created based on the display name you enter, but you can edit it to be whatever you like (as long as that doesn't conflict with anything that's already in use).

Comment: If I see this correctly, it's not possible to edit an existing group's email address in the UI, is it?